# Uncorrelated Real and Imaginary parts of a field in k-space: WHY?

Tags: correlation, autocorrelation, random-generation

I am in the process of generating a (real) Gaussian random field δ(x⃗ ) from a given power spectrum P(k). The way I define the power spectrum is, in Fourier space,

$\left\langle \delta(\vec{k}) \delta^*(\vec{k'}) \right\rangle = \delta(\vec{k}-\vec{k}') P(k)$

Now, I know that in order to do that, I need to draw separately two numbers, one for the Real and one for the Imaginary part of δ(k⃗ ), from a Guassian distribution with $\sigma^2=P(k)/2$ and then Inverse Fourier Transform the field from k-space to configuration space. What I do not understand is WHY the Real and Imaginary parts of the field in k-space are separate, totally uncorrelated. Can someone explain why?

EDIT:

Maybe, if I consider

$\left\langle \delta(\vec{k}) \delta^*(\vec{k}) \right\rangle = \left\langle |\delta(\vec{k})|^2 \right\rangle$,

I can then split the real and imaginary part? but still, why should this be 0, so that

$\left\langle [\text{Re} \delta(\vec{k})]^2 \right\rangle = \left\langle [\text{Im} \delta(\vec{k})]^2 \right\rangle = 0$??